# How can I enable MouseKeys on Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, windows-server-2008

I need to use a Windows 2008 Server without the mouse. For most functions I can use the keyboard but there are a couple of programs that doesn't have keyboard shortcuts; then, I was looking for the old "MouseKeys" function. I was looking in "Accesibilty" but cannot find that option: is this available on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using a little [AutoHotkey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/NumpadMouse.htm)